# Loading time more in Iphone safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html, load-time

I am trying to load my web page in mobile(IPhone), In chrome browser it taking only 3 seconds but in safari it taking almost 2 minutes to load a entire page, Is there any specific reason for this behavior? If is it so how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

If I had a link to your page I could tell you exactly what is causing the problem.

The second biggest issue with mobile carriers is the number of simultaneous requests allowed. A desktop will download about 6 page resources like CSS, JS, and images (http requests) simultaneously. Mobile, one, maybe two.

The biggest issue is the tower will often drop the radio signal between the phone and the tower between each request.  It takes about 2 seconds for the phone to reestablish the connection with the tower.

**With mobile it is very important to minimize the number of http requests per page.**

You want to make sure your http response header contains a `Content: keep-alive` for each http request.

Do not have unused CSS selectors.

Much the used CSS is inefficient and bloated by use of over qualified selectors.

Most web pages have multiple CSS files linked in, most unused.  Most pages only require a small amount of CSS which could fit withing the pages `<head><style>` rather than being linked in.

There should never be more than one CSS file.

Javascript should not be used to layout the page.  All JS does for layout is alter the HTML and CSS that should be have been done by the page designer.  When JS is needed, it should be loaded after the page renders.